# Como deixar a data nesse formato 27-Feb-17 as 21:52

Tags: php, mysql

coisa rápida preciso saber como deixo a data nesse formato 27-Feb-17 as 21:52 o meu código é este `<?php echo date('d/m/Y H:i', $news['published']); ?>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [documentação tem exatamente o que quer](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php), que é o `M` (para o mês ser no formato de `Jan` até `Dec`) e o `y` (para o ano ser no formato de dois números, onde `2017` é `17`).

Logo, basta alterar para o formato para:

```
echo date('d-M-y \a\s H:i', $news['published']);
```

**[Teste isto aqui.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3677c22d41e8ed1f27ece0413e669f915ab0da03)**

---

- O `d` é o dia com `0` a esquerda (`01`, `10`, `30`).
- O `M` é o mês em texto curto (`Jan`, `Feb`, `Dec`).
- O `y` é o ano com apenas dois dígitos (`00`, `01` `17`).
- O `H` é a hora no formato de 24 horas com zero a esquerda (`00`, `01`, `23`).
- O `i` é os minutos com zero a esquerda (`00`, `01`, `59`).

- O `-` e `:` são apenas textos normais.
- O `\a\s` é para escapar o texto `as`, *caso não utilize as `\` o `a` seria "trocado" por `am` e `pm` e o `s` seria "trocado" pelos segundos.*

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado pela ajuda.